# Can't create a package

Tags: ros, python, ros-fuerte, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with creating a package with roscreate-pkg. At the beginning I was create a package without any error messages. Now I get something like this while attempting to create a package:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 34, in 
import roscreate
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscreate/**init**.py", line 36, in 
import roscreate.core
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscreate/core.py", line 40, in 
import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

I have python-setuptools which should have the pkg_resources but somehow it is unable to find it.

I'm using ros-fuerte installed from package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68080/can%27t-create-a-package/) by [y0yster](https://answers.ros.org/users/5382/y0yster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WG-](https://answers.ros.org/users/2766/wg-/) on 2013-09-19**:
I also have this problem now. Don't know why. I first could create packages but now I can't anymore.

**Comment by [y0yster](https://answers.ros.org/users/5382/y0yster/) on 2013-09-19**:
I was able to solve the problem and I've forgotten to put the solution here. Now I'm doing this.
For me procedure below helped:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because of comment formatting, the commands are here:

sudo apt-get install curl

curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py

sudo python distribute_setup.py

sudo easy_install pip

---

Originally posted by [y0yster](https://answers.ros.org/users/5382/y0yster/) with karma: 26 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0